# How to make PUT working ionic/angular

Tags: angularjs, rest, express, ionic-framework

A RESTAPI has been created and now I want to update usersettings

The Controller

```
$scope.updateUser = function() {
//$scope._id = result.data._id; //+ $scope._id
$http.put(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/users/' + $scope._id, $scope.user).success(function(response) {

})};
```

The view:`

```
 <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="user.name">
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
    </label>
  </div>
  <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="updateUser()">
    Save
  </button>`
```

When a user is logged on and want to correct user profile, what is the correct approach writing this put function?

Right now when trying to change the name the terminal gives this:
http://prntscr.com/dac1d1
and nothing has been changed?

Comment: If your PUT from API returns any payload, you would either use that response to update the model or you can just reload the view as appropriate. What is the expected result you are looking to achieve?

Comment: right now i can do a PUT/Update but it sends blank name from the submit

Comment: From the given code it seems to be correct, but you might want to see what is the user on the scope you are passing in and make sure that the model has the updated values. Should be simple to debug and figure out.

Comment: yeah its working now. 
I had to define $scope.user = {}